# Trigger event.preventDefault(); only if condition is met - Jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I want to do is check if some of the values in a form (name, email) are not already in the database before I submit it.

I have a php script that works well and returns strings that corresponds to the issue, or "no output" in case there's nothing wrong.

The only problem I have is with the event.preventDefault(), which should only be called if the php script returns something other than "no output".
It doesn't work when it's within the get() call and I tried using an if statement, whether or not the error div is empty or not, but it didn't work either.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#signupForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $.get( "signupchecker.php", { name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val() } ).done(function ( data ) {
        if( data != "no output" ) {
            $( "#error" ).text( data );
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only problem I have is with the event.preventDefault(), which should only be called if the php script returns something other than "no output".

You can't reasonably do it that way. You'd have to use a synchronous ajax request, locking up the UI of the browser while the network operation was performed, which while *possible* is very poor UX. (And eventually won't be supported by jQuery anymore.)

Instead, always prevent the default, and if the PHP script returns a value saying the form is allowed to be submitted, call `submit` on the `DOMFormElement` (directly, not via jQuery). That will submit the form without running `submit` event handlers again.

E.g., something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signupForm").submit(function(event) {
        var thisForm = this;                // Remember the raw form element
        $.get("signupchecker.php", {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val()
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data != "no output") {
                $("#error").text(data);
            } else {
                thisForm.submit();          // Submit form w/o calling submit event handlers again
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();             // Always do this
    });
});
```

Note that since this means you're submitting the form only as the *indirect* result of user-initiated action, if the form's `target` is set to open a new window, you may fall afoul of popup blockers. (You also may not. :-) The browser can see that the XHR was initiated by a user event, and that the form submission is done in the completion of that XHR, so it could decide that it's okay...)

Comment: For some reason the form still isn't submited.
I checked and everything is going as it's supposed to up until this point.
Any ideas why?

Comment: Alright, it's working fine now!
But I also had another problem in my html, as I sheepishly gave the submit button an ID and name of "submit", and apparently javascript doesn't like that, as the name is redundant with atributes.

Comment: @user2825642: :-) Glad you figured it out. The problem with using the `id` `submit` is that form elements get automatic properties put on them for every element in the form with either an `id` or a `name`, using the `id`/`name`, which overwrites the `submit` method reference.